# spawn safe, platform-independent dummy process in Python

Tags: python, process, spawn

I'm writing some code that needs to run on different OS platforms and interact with separate processes. To write tests for it, I need to be able to create processes from python that do nothing but wait to be signaled to stop. I would like to be able to create some processes that recursively create more.

Also (this part might be a little strange), it would be best for my testing if I were able to create processes that weren't children of the creating process, so I could emulate conditions where, e.g., `os.waitpid` won't have permission to interact with the process, or where one process signals a factory to create a process rather than creating it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.6 the multiprocessing package has some stuff you might find useful.

There's a very simple example [on my github](https://github.com/mattyw/PublicSandpit/tree/master/python/multiproc). If you run spawner it will create 3 processes that run seperately, but use a channel to talk back to the spawner. So if you kill the spawner process the others you have started will die. I'm afraid there's a lot of redundant code in here, I'm in the middle of a refactoring, but I hope it gives a basic idea.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of the multiprocessing package. It seems like the right idea, but I see a lot of gotchas with it, and I still can't come up with any way to indirectly create processes (the 2nd part of my question).

Comment: I've got some old code that shows so pretty basic spawning, I'll see if I can find it and post it.

Comment: Alright, I've mostly figured out what I'm doing. I can create a child process that creates its own child for some of my test cases, and for others I can create siblings: one dummy process and a 2nd process to run test code on its sibling.